# Raspberry Pi 3B ripped off resistor (C187)

Tags: electronics

I need help on my Raspberry Pi 3B.
I accidentally broke a small part of it and it fell on the ground which is the reason I cannot find it anymore (It's just sooo small.).

That is an image of the Rpi 3B with a red sign where i ripped off that small piece of electronic.

[image]

I do not know what exactly it is but I expect it to be a resistor. Could you tell me what it is and where I can obtain more precise information on how I could replace it (If it is a resistor just the omage).
Next to let's call it resistor there is a code "C187" which is most likely referring to that resistor.

Comment: Is this a Pi 3B or a 3 B+? I can see [C187 on the Pi 3 B+ schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf) (C means that it's a *capacitor*, though, not a resistor), but it doesn't look like C187 is on the [Pi 3 B schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3b_1p2_reduced.pdf).

Comment: please post a picture of the damaged area on the board

Answer (score 1):

The part you're missing is a 100nF capacitor, most likely from the power part of schematics, which is there to reduce the noise. Unless you have a solid soldering skills for SMD parts, I'd recommend to ignore the missing part, your RPi should work just fine without it.